# Error "Internal Server Error" Heroku FastAPI

Tags: python, webservice, heroku, inteligencia-artificial, cv2

[image: Estoy tratando de subir una aplicación de fastAPI a heroku, es de reconocimiento facial con cv2 y mediapipe, pero al momento de subirlo y abrir el link me aparece el mensaje de "Internal Server Error"]

Les agradecería mucho si alguien sabe como resolver el problema o algun otro servidor que soporte mi aplicación con python.

Comment: No añadas imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/492220/edit) tu pregunta colocando el código como texto. También sería bueno que leyeras [ask] y que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla!

Comment: Un error, ¿cual error? ¿en cual código?